what exactly is happening to the FF if this is the timings diagram?
From a question in a digital electronics course, this is a timing diagram of an Edge triggered DFF, and I'm not sure how to even start since the input isn't stable in the T_setup, (we never really talked about what happens in those cases, it was considered forbidden) so my logic is that it shouldn't trigger an output until another T_setup+T_hold will take place (please correct me if I'm wrong.
this diagram in general is confusing, I don't understand the output curve (why would it curve?) and timings (it seems like it started changing logical state just after the first T_hold) and what is the last vertical dashed line for?
hopefully people here will be able to clear some of the misunderstandings I have.


It looks like it's indicating an example of borderline metastability.

Nate3384 - Hi, I know you said the diagram came from "a digital electronics course" but in the spirit of referencing copied / adapted material to the best of our ability, as stated in the site referencing rule, can you [edit] the question to improve that reference? If it's copied from a public website/PDF/video then add the name & link to the source. If the source is a printed book, private intranet, or other source which isn't online, see that rule for examples of the information which should be given e.g. title, author(s), publisher, edition etc. Can you do that? TY

@SamGibson it is from a practice paper we got, I don't know where they got the diagrams from.

@Nate3384 - I see, thanks. It's disappointing if people plagiarise material in a course, as that prevents the people receiving that course (like you) from properly referencing that material later. || I think I have found the original source (the image you were given was slightly adapted from the source material). I'll add that reference which I found into the question shortly.

This diagram is showing metastable behavior. This can happen when your inputs violate the set-up and/or hold time requirements of the flip-flop in just the right way so that the flip-flop "doesn't know" what output to produce.
The set-up and hold-times are meant to represent the worst-case range of timings that might produce this behavior. So you can't count on this behavior happening every time you violate set-up or hold time, but you must satisfy the set-up and hold times to be sure it won't happen.
When the output is at an intermediate voltage level we say it is in a metastable state. Similar to a ball balanced on the top of a pointed stick, it may remain there for a brief time but eventually the forces at play (gravity in the ball-on-a-stick example) will pull it away to a stable state (the ball resting on the ground).

my logic is that it shouldn't trigger an output until another T_setup+T_hold will take place

It will produce an output. The output might match the previous state of the input or the new state of the input, but it will be one or the other ... eventually.
That intermediate-voltage region seen in the output line of your timing diagram can last for an indefinite period of time, but will eventually settle to one logic level or the other due to thermal variations and positive feedback.
If you made this timing violation several times and recorded all the outputs on a single scope screen, it might look something like this:

(Image source: R. Ginosar, "Metastability and
Synchronizers: A Tutorial")

I don't understand the output curve (why would it curve?)

It's a "metastable state" and this curve is characteristic of its behavior. It must "get stuck" in the middle of the voltage range otherwise positive feedback in the logic circuit would quickly push the voltage to one logic level or the other. (That means if the "locked in value" were not in the middle we just wouldn't see the metastable behavior, not that other values aren't possible)

and timings (it seems like it started changing logical state just after the first T_hold)

That's because \$t_h\$ is typically closely related to the propagation delay of signals through the logic in question.

what is the last vertical dashed line for?

It's not called out explicitly but I think it is showing the defined propagation delay (\$t_{pd}\$) for this device, indicating that this characteristic behavior has been violated because the input operating conditions were violated.

I think I understand, so because the input data wasn't stable at $t_{\text{setup}}$ the output entered this metastable state which it eventually settled on an output of 1.
just to be sure, is the output after the metastable state correct by coincidence or is it guaranteed to eventually end on the initially expected output (just with the timing out of order and metastability)

@Nate3384, yes, but if you ran the same sequence again it might end up at 0 instead. It's probably worth reading the document I stole the image from.

@Nate3384 there is no "correct" output in this case. Maybe the "correct" output is 0 because that's what the input was at the beginning of the set-up time, or maybe the "correct" output is 1 because that's what the input was at the end of the hold time. There's no guarantee it will be one or the other, and neither is more correct than the other.
